# Editing chip list on click

Tags: angular

I am using angular 6. I want the the mat-chip-list editable on click.Is there any way to edit the chip list using angular material 6??

```
 <mat-chip *ngFor="let item of emailForm.get('users')['controls']; let i=index;" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable" 
    (removed)="remove(i, 'email', emailForm)" [formGroupName]="i"
    color="primary" matTooltip="{{item.value}}" 
    matTooltipClass="add-to-team" 
     (click)="onChipClick(i, emailForm)">
```